# npm peer dependency resolution conditions WARN vs ERR

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install

I have two projects with same problem but it's unclear why npm resolves them differently:

1. https://github.com/Sairyss/domain-driven-hexagon

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: domain-driven-hexagon@2.0.0
npm ERR! Found: slonik@31.4.2
npm ERR! node_modules/slonik
npm ERR!   slonik@"^31.2.4" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer slonik@"27 - 29" from @slonik/migrator@0.11.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@slonik/migrator
npm ERR!   @slonik/migrator@"^0.11.3" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

2. https://github.com/ddd-by-examples/library-nestjs

```
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: rxjs-for-await@0.0.2
npm WARN Found: rxjs@7.4.0
npm WARN node_modules/rxjs
npm WARN   rxjs@"^7.0.0" from the root project
npm WARN   5 more (@nestjs/common, @nestjs/config, @nestjs/core, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer rxjs@"^6.0.0" from rxjs-for-await@0.0.2
npm WARN node_modules/rxjs-for-await
npm WARN   rxjs-for-await@"0.0.2" from @nrwl/node@13.2.2
npm WARN   node_modules/@nrwl/node
npm WARN   1 more (@nrwl/tao)
npm WARN
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: rxjs@6.6.7
npm WARN node_modules/rxjs
npm WARN   peer rxjs@"^6.0.0" from rxjs-for-await@0.0.2
npm WARN   node_modules/rxjs-for-await
npm WARN     rxjs-for-await@"0.0.2" from @nrwl/node@13.2.2
npm WARN     node_modules/@nrwl/node
npm WARN     1 more (@nrwl/tao)
```

both of them have conflicting peer dependency with root project dependency but with first project it's resolved with ERR(unable to resolve dependency tree) and second with WARN(overriding peer dependency)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first example has two requirements that cannot both be true at the same time: `slonik@31.4.2` and `slonik@"27 - 29"`. There is no version of `slonik` that both packages can use, and npm isn't capable of building a dependency tree with two different versions of the same package in it. It *has* to resolve down to one version that meets all requirements, and if that can't be done, then it will fail and throw an error. *Because `slonik@"27 - 29"` specifies an upper limit to the versions that it accepts, npm assumes that version 30+ are known to not work rather than just not known to work.*

The second example has two requirements that (confusingly) also disagree with each other: `rxjs@"^7.0.0"` and `rxjs@"^6.0.0"`. The caret means that any minor or bugfix version is allowed, but a new major version is not - so one requirement is for version 7.x.y and the other is for version 6.x.y. However, because there isn't an upper bound set by the second dependency, npm tries to resolve this anyway, and uses the higher version number. This can cause bugs, which is why there's a warning, but it's not guaranteed to break.

You can read more about npm and semantic versioning [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/about-semantic-versioning).

Since the first example has a dependency from the root of the project, you can simply change the version of `slonik` you are using to `^29.0.0` or (preferably) look for a more up-to-date version of `@slonik/migrator` that uses a more recent version of `slonik`.